# Why is Furch's "knotted hole ball" not shellable?

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, geometric-topology, knot-theory, discrete-geometry

I'm trying to work through the example below, but I need some explanation as to why K' is not shellable. If we try to shell it, where would we get stuck?.

[image]

Here are some relevant definitions.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note that $K$ has $m^3$ cubes as its facets. Removing some of them you end up with $K'$ which has $m^3-q$ cubes as its facets, where $q$ is the number of removed cubes. The boundary complexes of both $K$ and $K'$ are $2$-dimensional, the one of $K$ consists of $6m^2$ squares, the one of $K'$ has more squares. The sides $S$ and $S'$ are not faces in the complex $K$, but subcomplexes, each consisting of $m^2$ squares. Removing one square from $S'$ you get a subcomplex consisting of $m^2-1$ squares whose support is indeed not a polytope, but that's not an issue since it is not a face!

Comment: Thanks. I got it now. I edited the question so that others don't have to answer those parts again. I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

By analogy with Lemma 5.2, indeed, let's prove that pure 3D complex  $G$ that contains a knotted (in $G$) curve with all edges except one on the boundary of $G$ can not be shellable.

Suppose $G$ is such a shellable complex with minimal number of facets. Let the curve be $\gamma=C\cup e$, where $C$ is a path in boundary of $G$; let $A$ and $B$ be the vertices of $e$. Then remove the last (in the shelling order) facet $F_N$ from $G$ and get a smaller shellable complex $\hat{G}$. We claim is that $\hat{G}$ also contains a a knotted (in $\hat{G}$) curve with all edges except one on the boundary of $\hat{G}$. Once this is established, we are done since $G$ was assumed to be minimal complex with such properties.

Now, why does $\hat{G}$ contain a knotted loop with all but one edges on the boundary?  We claim $e$ could not have been an edge of $F_N$, for otherwise  we could homotope the path $C$, keeping $A$ and $B$ fixed, to a path in boundary of $F_N$ and get a knotted curve in the boundary of $F_N$, which is not possible since that boundary is a 2-sphere.  So the edge $e$ was not an edge of $F_n$, and then it is still an interior edge of $\hat{G}$. Now we can homotope $C$, keeping keeping $A$ and $B$ fixed, to a path $\hat{C}$ in the boundary of $\hat{G}$, and $\hat{\gamma}=\hat{C}\cup e$ is a knotted loop in $\hat{C}$ with exactly one edge not on the boundary.